# Ruby disappears after halt on Vagrant box

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, rbenv

Working on Ruby on Rails projects from a Windows (7 x64), I now want to go further and use vagrant with VirtualBox for a prod like dev environment.

Based on the dedicated [RailsCast tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/292-virtual-machines-with-vagrant), then discovering that now Vagrant as to be installed with their installer instead of the `gem install vagrant`, I finally got the (Ubuntu) precise32 [vagrant provided box](http://www.vagrantbox.es) up and running \o/

**My problem is that if I do a `vagrant halt` on host, next time I'll do a `vagrant up` (even without changing anything), the loaded system doesn't know about Ruby anymore !**

Here is what I do after the needed apt-get install:

```sh
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.profile
source .profile
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
cd ruby-build/
sudo ./install.sh
rbenv install 1.9.3-p327
rbenv rehash
rbenv global 1.9.3-p327
ruby -v
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does the compiled 1.9.3-p327 exist in `~/.rbenv/versions`? It should not vanish without reason. BTW: I recommend installing `reben-rehash` gem to avoid rehash all the time.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I'm away from this (host) box at the moment so I won't be able to confirm until next week.
In the meantime, I decided to try the RVM alternative to check if it's my linux skills or my rbEnv skills that fails me :/
(Thanks for the recommendation, I chose to keep this subject as simple as possible...)

Comment: Not really answering my answer, but found a workaround...with RVM !

[Renaud Cuny](http://renaud-cuny.com/en/contact.html) created a full ["ruby install with RVM" tutorial on Ubuntu 12.04](http://renaud-cuny.com/en/blog/2013-04-11-step-by-step-ruby-rvm-installation-ubuntu-server/) which solves all my problems !!

I'll investigate later on my other server (when I'll be back in HQ), but for now, I got my Rails env up and running !
Thanks Renaud ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Ubuntu's bash man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/bash.1.html):

> When bash is invoked as an  interactive  login  shell,  or  as  a  non-
>   interactive  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes
>   commands from the  file  /etc/profile,  if  that  file  exists.   After
>   reading  that  file,  it  looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and
>   ~/.profile, in that order, and **reads and  executes  commands  from  the
>   first  one  that exists and is readable**.  The --noprofile option may be
>   used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

**If** you have `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` in place, preventing your `~/.profile` from being read. rbenv never gets initialized, so ruby appears to be missing.

Placing those in `~/.bash_profile` should keep ruby visible upon subsequent logins.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, I forgot about this thanks to my workaround. Indeed, the `.bash_profile` handling can be tricky ! But rbenv has greatly improved and it now checks for a good `.bash_profile` file. Thanks again !